# RMAN Duplicate Target Database ORA-19511: Error received from media manager layer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, standby, dataguard

I am trying to build a standby database in a Data Guard configuration using RMAN Duplicate Target Database For Standby Dorecover.

All the rman backupsets are there in Netbackup and I can see the inventory of backup pieces using the RMAN views.

However, the Duplicate Target Database command is failing with:

```
channel p4: starting datafile backup set restore
channel p4: restoring control file
channel p4: reading from backup piece c-2404308342-20160306-02
channel p4: ORA-19870: error while restoring backup piece c-2404308342-20160306-02
ORA-19507: failed to retrieve sequential file, handle="c-2404308342-20160306-02", parms=""
ORA-27029: skgfrtrv: sbtrestore returned error
ORA-19511: Error received from media manager layer, error text:
Backup file <c-2404308342-20160306-02> not found in NetBackup catalog
```

Basically, the backup pieces are there, but RMAN/Netbackup is saying that they are not there.

Do you know why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please try validating the restore with a validate restore command. It should take some time but will notify you of any backup corruptions. 
e.g. RMAN > restore database validate;

Thanks
Sabiha